Mulberry tree very close to septic system
I have 2 mulberry trees (both are already 8 feet high) that are growing fast and 1 is only 5 feet from my septic system access point and gravel driveway. The other is 8 feet away. Do I need to cut both down? I’m afraid they will destroy my septic system - access point and piping.

upvoted; 2.5m high is not too large to move. How to do it is a separate topic.

It would be advisable to remove both trees due to the potential risk that the mulberry tree's roots provide to your driveway and septic system. By doing this, you can avoid future damage to the piping and entry point of your septic system, which could need expensive repairs.
Lastly, losing the trees is regrettable, but safeguarding your infrastructure is probably a safer option if you made up your mind to keep them then I would like to suggest you that consult with a professional arborist or a septic system specialist who can provide you with more tailored advice.
If you decide to keep them, consulting with a professional arborist or a septic system specialist can provide more tailored advice.
